# is there any specific way to write click house curl insert query?

Tags: php, curl, clickhouse

I am using click house with PHP CURL.   curl query for select is working fine. But when do the insert it doesn't work. This is the query I am using for inserting.

```
http://localhost:8123/?query=INSERT%20INTO%20vas_services%20VALUES%20(, 0710715609, 'Ebill',1,'2020-02-25 00:01:01')
```

Can any one say is there any incorrect thing in above query or alternative solution for the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `GET` for insert action.
Consider using `POST`, then you can use `body` to pass the parameters. Also - never use whole query as argument of any kind.

You should have query like this:

```
INSERT INTO vas_services VALUES(:first_name...)
```

Using raw queries is very dangerous, as you could easily get SQL injection attacks. Also using raw parameters is not advised - always use functions that makes your SQL parameters validated and properly escaped e.g. you would use PDO functions e.g. [bindParam](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

After that you would call your action like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32112981/3741729).

Comment: `VALUES(:first_name -- ` it stops streaming parser and turn on slow memory-greedy parser. Dont do that for inserts.